# Counting Yes and No Answers from React Form in an Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, forms, material-ui

I am creating a React form using Material UI components. I have an empty array `questionAns` that I am using to keep track of the responses. I want to add an element, say `yes` to the array when the Yes radio button is selected on the form. Here is a subset of the form I am building:

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import {
  Button,
  Radio,
  RadioGroup,
  FormControlLabel,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  FormHelperText,
  FormGroup,
  Checkbox,
  Grid,
  Box,
} from "@mui/material";


...


<FormControl error={Boolean(errors.question1)}>
          <FormLabel component="legend">
            {Records[0].question}
          </FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup row aria-label="question1" name="question1">
            <FormControlLabel
              value="Yes"
              control={
                <Radio
                  {...register("awQuestion1", {
                    required: "Please select a response.",
                  })}
                />
              }
              label="Yes"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              value="No"
              control={
                <Radio
                  {...register("awQuestion1", {
                    required: "Please select a response.",
                  })}
                />
              }
              label="No"
            />
          </RadioGroup>
          <FormHelperText style={{ color: "#d32f2f" }}>
            {errors.question1?.message}
          </FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
```

How can I incorporate some sort of write function to accommodate my desired functionality? I'm not very familiar with JavaScript and React, but I would like to incorporate this hopefully simple feature.

I have a series of questions in the same structure as above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a hook - `useState` - to keep track of the "Yes" answers, for example at the top of your component declare an `answersArray` state and its setter function:

```
const [answersArray, setAnswersArray] = useState([]);
```

Then on the radio buttons add an `onChange` prop

```
onChange={(e)=>{
    if(e.checked) setAnswersArray((prevState)=> [...prevState, "Yes"]) //"No" on the no button
}
```

This is just the jist check out the docs for a better tutorial

https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState

Comment: `<Radio
                  onChange={(e)=>{
                    if(e.checked) setAnswersArray((prevState)=> [...prevState, "Yes"]; //"No" on the no button
                  }
                  {...register("awQuestion1", {
                    required: "Please select a response.",
                  })}` I did this and got an error Unexpected token, expected. I tried a comma instead of a semicolon, but I received the same error. Am I missing something @LaurenceSummers ?

Comment: Missing ) at the end, my code was just done on mobile as a general jist, don’t copy and paste it try reading the docs and this https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6_spread.asp